# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Why does this work:

```
Declare @latitude varchar = '34.343';
Declare @decLatitude Decimal(9,6);
Set @decLatitude = CAST(@latitude AS Decimal(9,6));
```

But this doesn't?

```
Declare @longitude varchar = '-92.6424';
Declare @decLongitude Decimal(9,6);
Set @decLongitude = CAST(@longitude AS Decimal(9,6));
```

It returns the error "Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric".

This is on an Azure SQL database.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: Yeah, I was overly tired and wasn't thinking straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are getting what you wanted in your first query ?

```
Declare @latitude varchar = '34.343';
Declare @decLatitude Decimal(9,6);
Set @decLatitude = CAST(@latitude AS Decimal(9,6));
```

Did you examine what is the value you stored in both of the variables ?

```
select  @latitude, @decLatitude
```

If you don't specify a size for the `varchar`, it is assumed `1`

```
Declare @latitude varchar = '34.343';
```

so basically you are assigning `3` to `@latitude`
and converting `3` to decimal is fine

In you second query, you are you are assigning a `'-'` to the @latitude
So converting `'-'` to decimal will cause an error !

So declaring a varchar with size will work in your second query

```
Declare @longitude varchar(10) = '-92.6424';
```

Comment: And *this* boys and girls is why, after programming for 15 hours straight, you go eat a sandwich and go to bed.  Thanks Squirrel, and good night.